# Codeigniter - Get sum of a column in table according to year and should show it in input tag

Tags: php, html, ajax, codeigniter

I have Codeigniter project and I need to get sum of profit of budgets according to the year that mentioned in dropdown.

[image]

I have written the codes as mentioned below.
But, when I am selecting 2021 option, it is not working.
Could you please show me the error of coding in below?

***View***

```
    <form>
              <div class="box-body">
               
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="example">Select Year</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="year" id="SelectOption">
                      <option value="">Select</option>
                      <option value="2015">2015</option>
                      <option value="2016">2016</option>
                      <option value="2017">2017</option>
                      <option value="2018">2018</option>
                      <option value="2019">2019</option>
                      <option value="2020">2020</option>
                      <option value="2021">2021</option>
                      
                        
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              

 <div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="example">Profit</label>
 <input type="text" id="profitdiv" name="txtname" class="form-control" readonly>
 </div>
 </div>
              
 </form>


<script>

document.getElementById('SelectOption').addEventListener('change', function() 
{var val = $( "#SelectOption" ).val();
    
  console.log(val)
  if(val === '2021') {
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Reports/get_profit",
                data:{val:val},
                success: function(data){
                    $('#profitdiv').html(data);
                }
            });
    }
}
</script>
```

***Controller***

```
public function get_profit()
    {
        $this->load->model('Reports_model');
        $data=$this->Reports_model->select_profit();
        if($data!=='')
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', "Profit Show Succesfully"); 
        }else{
         $this->session->set_flashdata('error', "Sorry, Profit Showing Failed.");
        }
        redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        

    }
```

***Model***

```
function select_profit()
    {
      $this->db->select_sum("budget_tbl.surplus ");
       $this->db->from("budget_tbl");
       $this->db->like(‘surplus’,'2021-','after');
       $qry=$this->db->get();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How you record the date in your database? (format )

pass the year through your model

```
$year = $this -> input -> post("val")    
$data=$this->Reports_model->select_profit($year);
```

.

```
function select_profit($year)
    {
      $this->db->select_sum("budget_tbl.surplus ");
       $this->db->from("budget_tbl");
       $this->db->where(‘surplus >=’,$year.'-01-01');
       $qry=$this->db->get();
       return $qry -> result();    
    }
```

Comment: Data type is timestamp.
The format is like this 2021-08-09 03:36:12

Comment: so add time to it , '-01-01 00:00:00'

Comment: Thnx. Still not working friend. :( JavaScript on my view file may have error. But I couldn't understand the error.

Comment: send the error message or screenshot of error

Comment: There is no error message. but profit is not loaded to the view

Comment: In my project, it has a generated date on budget table for every budget. The budget table has surplus column, generated date etc. I need to get sum of surplus for only 2021 when selecting 2021 option of dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

full code

**HTML**

```
<form >
    <div class="box-body" >

        <div class="col-md-6" >
            <div class="form-group" >
                <label for="example" >Select Year</label >
                <select class="form-control" name="year" id="Year" >
                    <option value="" >Select</option >
                    <option value="2015" >2015</option >
                    <option value="2016" >2016</option >
                    <option value="2017" >2017</option >
                    <option value="2018" >2018</option >
                    <option value="2019" >2019</option >
                    <option value="2020" >2020</option >
                    <option value="2021" >2021</option >
                 </select >
            </div >
        </div >
    </div >


    <div class="col-md-6" >
        <div class="form-group" >
            <label for="example" >Profit</label >
            <input type="text" id="profitdiv" name="txtname" class="form-control" readonly >
        </div >
    </div >

</form >


<script >

    $("#Year").change(function () {
        var Year = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url (); ?>index/get_profit",
            data: {Year: Year},
            success: function (data) {
                $('#profitdiv').html(data);
            }
        });

    })


</script >
```

**Controller**

```
public function get_profit ()
        {
            $this -> load -> model ( 'Reports_model' );
            $year = $this -> input -> post ( "val" );
            $data = $this -> Reports_model -> select_profit ( $year );

            if (!empty( $data )) {
                echo "Profit Show Succesfully";
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, Profit Showing Failed";
            }

        }
```

**Model**

```
function select_profit($year)
    {
      $this->db->select_sum("budget_tbl.surplus ");
       $this->db->from("budget_tbl");
       $this->db->where(‘surplus >=’,$year.'-01-01 00:00:00');
       $qry=$this->db->get();
       return $qry -> result();    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you will have to match the year to your date column.

In your existing code wherein you want sum of surplus for the year 2021, change the following line of your model:

```
$this->db->like(‘surplus’,'2021-','after');
```

to

```
$this->db->like(‘name_of_generated_date_column’,'2021-','after');
```

Add this line:

```
return $query->result();
```

To make it work for any selected year:

As mentioned in the post above, extract the year in your controller:

```
$year = $this -> input -> post("val")
```

Send and retrieve data to/from your model

```
$data=$this->Reports_model->select_profit($year);
```

In the model:

```
function select_profit($year)  
    {  
...  
       $this->db->like(‘name_of_generated_date_column’,$year,'after');  
...  
return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.